# Convert a function that has ES6 promise to a function that doesn't

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have this code that uses `ES6` promise, and i want to convert it to a code with doesn't have `Promise`.
the code is long but the promise is used only in this part:

```
function(e, t, r) {
        "use strict";
        e.exports = function(e) {
            var t = new XMLHttpRequest;
            return new Promise(function(r, n) {
                t.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (4 == this.readyState)
                        if (200 == this.status) {
                            var e = JSON.parse(this.response);
                            r(e)
                        } else {
                            var t = JSON.parse(this.response);
                            n(t)
                        }
                }, t.onerror = function(e) {
                    n(new Error(this.statusText))
                }, t.open("GET", e, !0), t.send(null)
            })
        }
    }, function(e, t, r) {
        "use strict";

        function n(e, t) {
            o.options.key = e;
            for (var r in t) o.options[r] = t[r]
        }
        var o = r(3),
            u = r(4);
        e.exports = function(e, t, r, i) {
            if (!t && "function" == typeof i) return i(new Error("API Key is required"));
            if (!t) throw new Error("API Key is required");
            n(t, r);
            var s = u.stringify(o.options);
            if ("function" != typeof i) return e(o.URL + s);
            e(o.URL + s).then(function(e) {
                return i(null, e)
            }).catch(function(e) {
                return i(e)
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by replace? Do you want to convert it to callback?

Comment: do you want to use ```async/await``` or ```callback``` instead of ```promises```?

Comment: @JamshidAsadzadeh Yes i want to convert it to callback

Comment: @DanyalImran no i want to use Ecmascript 3 or 4, meaning to support a very old browser. i don't want to use any plugin, because it doesn't make sense to include a plugin for only one function, you know what i mean

Comment: SO isn't for asking other people to write your code for you. You should ask specific programming questions here. I have fixed the code anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have converted it to callback based. The callback format is as follows:

`callback(err, data)` if `err` is not null then an error has occurred otherwise the `err` parameter would be null and the `data` parameter would have the value.

```
function(e, t, r) {
  "use strict";
  e.exports = function(e, callback) {
      var t = new XMLHttpRequest;
      t.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (4 == this.readyState)
              if (200 == this.status) {
                  var e = JSON.parse(this.response);
                  callback(e);
              } else {
                  var t = JSON.parse(this.response);
                  callback(null, t)
              }
      }, t.onerror = function(e) {
          callback(new Error(this.statusText))
      }, t.open("GET", e, !0), t.send(null)
  }
}, function(e, t, r) {
  "use strict";

  function n(e, t) {
      o.options.key = e;
      for (var r in t) o.options[r] = t[r]
  }
  var o = r(3),
      u = r(4);
  e.exports = function(e, t, r, i) {
      if (!t && "function" == typeof i) return i(new Error("API Key is required"));
      if (!t) throw new Error("API Key is required");
      n(t, r);
      var s = u.stringify(o.options);
      if ("function" != typeof i) return e(o.URL + s);
      e(o.URL + s).then(function(e) {
          return i(null, e)
      }).catch(function(e) {
          return i(e)
      })
  }
}
```

Or you could use a Promise pollyfill:

https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise

https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-polyfill

Comment: the function that has the promise is used at the bottom `return e(o.URL + s);
      e(o.URL + s).then(function(e) {
          return i(null, e)
      }).catch(function(e) {
          return i(e)
      })` error `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: `e` is used as a parameter, so you have no control over it in here, you would have to modify the `e` function that is passed as a parameter

Comment: i see, is there a way to convert the whole code using `babeljs` for example?

Comment: not that I know of, sorry. although there is someone who tried to this, I don't know if he was successful or not. https://github.com/jamestalmage/unpromisify

Comment: or you could use a Promise pollyfill, I have updated my answer to include the links

Comment: i tried it but it gives me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +=` with no error line number (on my laptop it works fine but on an old mobile that doesn't support promises it gives me that error )

Comment: Did you use a pollyfill?

Comment: yes i did include `    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.auto.min.js"></script> `

Comment: only add   https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.auto.js   then add another script tag with `ES6Promise.polyfill()`

Comment: You mean i add `es6-promise.auto.js` then at the bottom include the code that has `Promises` like the one i posted above? if that what you mean then i got the same error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +=`

Comment: 1-es6-promise.auto.js    2-`ES6Promise.polyfill() `      3-Your code

Comment: you mean like this: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.auto.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">ES6Promise.polyfill();</script>` if that's what you meant then i got the same error, if not please show me what you mean in code

Comment: Yes meant that, I'm sorry but I have nothing more to add to that